# SonarQube 5.3 Findbugs 3.0.1 0 is not a value stack offset

Tags: findbugs, illegalargumentexception, sonarqube5.3

Analysing an Ant project with SonarQube 5.3 Findbugs 3.0.1 got following stacktrace:

```
[sonar:sonar] The following errors occurred during analysis: 
[sonar:sonar]   Can't get stack offset 0 from [] @ 271 in com.mypackage.MyClass.myMethod : (Lorg.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;Lorg.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;Ljavax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;Ljavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;)Lorg.apache.struts.action.ActionForward; 
[sonar:sonar]     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 0 is not a value stack offset 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.OpcodeStack.getStackItem(OpcodeStack.java:3100) 
[sonar:sonar]       At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.sawOpcode(PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.java:289) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.DismantleBytecode.visit(DismantleBytecode.java:883) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.BetterVisitor.visitCode(BetterVisitor.java:218) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.visitCode(PreorderVisitor.java:235) 
[sonar:sonar]       At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.visitCode(PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.java:202) 
[sonar:sonar]       At org.apache.bcel.classfile.Code.accept(Code.java:135) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.doVisitMethod(PreorderVisitor.java:307) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.visitJavaClass(PreorderVisitor.java:395) 
[sonar:sonar]       At org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.accept(JavaClass.java:215) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BytecodeScanningDetector.visitClassContext(BytecodeScanningDetector.java:38) 
[sonar:sonar]       At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.visitClassContext(PossiblyRedundantMethodCalls.java:174) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:76) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:1089) 
[sonar:sonar]       At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:283) 
[sonar:sonar]       At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:211) 
[sonar:sonar]       At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
[sonar:sonar]       At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
[sonar:sonar]       At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
[sonar:sonar]       At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
[sonar:sonar]  
[sonar:sonar] 12:00:12.936 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 3.0.1 done: 59558 ms
```

This error did not occur with SonarQube 5.1.1 and I recently updated version to 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your plugin **Sonar-FindBugs** to the latest version. FB-contrib, the FindBugs plugin visible in the stacktrace, was update to its latest version 6.6.1.

If the issue is not resolved, you can report an issue here : https://github.com/mebigfatguy/fb-contrib/issues

Comment: Unfortunately I could not evaluate the answer. I was forced to make a new version update (5.3 -> 5.4) and with this the problem stopped happening. Thank you anyway.